# select mat-table row programmatically

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-table based component in my application that allows for the user to select a row by clicking on it. Based on the selected table row, the code shows additional information/details about that row in an adjacent expansion panel. When the page loads, none of the table rows are selected - hence the details panel in empty. What is the best way to select a table row (let's say, the first one) programmatically?

The current row selection is based on invoking a click handler on the mat-row that was clicked that sets a property 'selectedRowIndex' to the row.id field. This causes the ngClass for the row to bind to a highlight css class:

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex == row.id}" (click)="highlight(row)"></mat-row>
```

But if I wanted a 'default' selection of the first row, how would I accomplish that? This should be a pretty standard usecase for many developers, I would think.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `[ngClass]` or `[ngStyle]`.

I have created a demo on  **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-mat-table-row-programatically?file=app/table-basic-example.ts)**. I hope this will help/guide to you/others.

> Component.html

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="highlight(row)" [ngClass]="{'highlightTableColor': selectedRowIndex == row.position}"></tr>
```

> Component.ts

```
highlight(row){
    this.selectedRowIndex=row.position;
}
```

Comment: Krishna, I am already doing that in the little code excerpt I had included in my question. I wanted a default selection of the first row as soon as the table loads without any user action.
Anyway, I have figured it out now:
On the table add a cdkObserveContent handler:
      `<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSourceTable" matSort aria-label="Faults" (cdkObserveContent)="tableContentChanged()">`
and in that handler invoke the highlight handler to highlight the row:
  `tableContentChanged() {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.highlight(this.dataSourceTable.data[0]);
    });
  }`

Comment: When table load you can call function with 0 index data to then first data is also selected .

Comment: this.highlight(this.dataSource.data[0])

Comment: I hope this will help to you

Comment: Thanks Krishna. That's what I did. Part of the problem was to determine when the table would finish rendering. Using the cdkObserveContent property solved that.

Comment: tried it and doesn't work your stackbliz example on ff.64-linux

Answer (score 0):

Adding a formal answer:

On the table add a cdkObserveContent handler (this allows the table to load first):

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSourceTable" matSort aria-label="Faults" (cdkObserveContent)="tableContentChanged()">
```

and in that handler invoke the highlight handler to highlight the row:

```
tableContentChanged() { 
   this.zone.run(() => { 
     this.highlight(this.dataSourceTable.data[0]); 
   }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made a long time to find a working answer so will try to be concise. In my case, I pass through a http request so through an observable but

1. declare an `onclick` event on mat-row on `component.html`

   ```js
   <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsArray" 
     (click)="onRowClicked(row)"
     [ngClass]="{ 'selected' : row === currentEntity }">Content</mat-row>
   ```
2. on `<any>component.ts` my onRowClicked looks like

   ```js
   onRowClicked(row: any) {
       this.logger.debug('-----> Row clicked', row);
       this.currentEntity = Company.fromAny(row);
   }
   ```
3. finally in `<any>component.ts` in my `ngOnInit()`

   ```js
   ngOnInit() {
       // Some things
       let retreivedData = myWebService.getSomeData()
       onRowClicked(retreivedData)
   }
   ```

So that the path is `ngOnInit=>onRowClicked=>currentEntity === row`